# python 2.7: Testing text file in idle

Tags: python

I m using the command `testFile = open("test.txt")` to open a simple text file and received the following: Does such errors occur due to the version of python one uses?

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test.txt

Comment: Well, it looks like `test.txt` doesn't exist in the directory you're running IDLE from.

Comment: no, this is a standard error with standard error code for not finding a file

Comment: How about python 2.7 vs 3.2

Comment: @Maton No. The version of Python doesn't matter for this at all. The issue is that the file isn't where you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

add an "a+" mode argument on to your open, this will create the file if it doesn't exist:

```
testFile = open("test.txt", "a+")
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for opening file is:

file object = open(file_name [, access_mode][, buffering])

As you have not mentioned access_mode(optional), default is 'Read'. But if file 'test.txt' does not exists in the folder where you are executing script, it will through an error as you got.

To correct it, either add access_mode as "a+" or give full file path e.g. C:\test.txt (assuming windows system)

Answer (score 0):

The error is independent from the version, but it is not clear 
what you want to do with your file.
If you want to read from it and you get such an error, it means that your file is not where you think it is. In any case you should write a line like `testFile = open("test.txt","r")`.
If you want to create a new file and write in it, you will have a line like
testFile = open("test.txt","w"). Finally, if your file already exists and you want to add things on it, use `testFile = open("test.txt","a")` (after having moved the file at the correct place). If your file is not in the directory of the script, you will use commands to find your file and open it.